# Expected identifier before "{" token error

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ios-simulator

Hi I am making a demo off of "Beginning iphone Games Development" and I have the `Expected identifier before "{"` error on:

```
-(CGFloat) angle:
{
    return rotation*180.0/3.141592;
}
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the colon after `angle`. The colon is telling the compiler that your method takes an argument, and it's reporting an error because there isn't one.